# Does this attack on RSA keys reveals a major flaw, or this is no big deal with good entropy?

Tags: rsa, entropy, key

William Kuszmaul published a study of an attack for RSA public keys on his blog https://algorithmsoup.wordpress.com/2019/01/15/breaking-an-unbreakable-code-part-1-the-hack/

The basic idea is, when people use poor PRNG to generate RSA keys, detect common factors in the bilions of public keys available online. Then it is easy to factor and crack the public keys.

While this not a new thing that poor PRNG *or poor entropy* lead to weak keys, the algorithm seems to speed up considerably the detection.

Will this force users to use larger keys (abandon 2048 bits keys ?) or abandon RSA sooner in favor of EC cryptography ?

Or maybe this is no big deal, and ... we just should not generate keys on an old Debian after reboot ?

Comment: 'larger keys' wouldn't help; 4 billion bit RSA keys using the same weak PRNG are just as weak. Badly-chosen EC keys are nearly as bad, and in addition _standard_ ECDSA leaks the key if the 'random' nonce k used at signature time repeats -- but rfc6979 or EdDSA doesn't, nor ECDH or ECIES if _either_ party is good. But yes, avoiding systems that are obsolete _and_ defective is a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

The original [2012 paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/064.pdf) the blog references attributes it mostly to using an improperly seeded PRNG, though at least some of the keys had deeper unknown issues:

> We also encountered seven components that we find harder to explain,
>   the most remarkable one being a K<sub>9</sub>, a complete graph on nine vertices.

(vertices being primes, so they found keys using every possible pair of primes from these 9)

If you're using well known software to generate your keys, I wouldn't worry about anything more than proper seeding, which is known to be an issue especially in embedded devices shortly after rebooting.

---

For the Debian OpenSSL issue you mention though, it's not just after reboot that you have to worry, those keys only have entropy from the PID (15 bits by default) no matter when they are generated.